# Problem loading icon in WPF App when Windows is set to larger font size

Tags: wpf, icons

I'm having a peculiar problem in a WPF-app I've written. It has a single window that loads a single user control after some user input which works perfectly fine for almost all users. Two users reported that the app crashed on launch which sent me investigating.

The culprit I found was that they had set the overall font size in Windows to "Extra large" under Display Properties. When I switched it back to "Normal" they could load the app just fine.

Since I can't post images here is a link to the image that shows where to set the font size if anyone wonders: http://content.screencast.com/users/CarloToribio/folders/Jing/media/f6791854-d6ad-4aae-a3f8-42e4140ad1aa/2010-07-26_1235.png

These users are old and have bad sight so they really need the "Extra large" font size to work with Windows so I need to solve this somehow. The icon that is being loaded is a .ico with several sizes from 16x16 up to 256x256.

Does anyone know what could affect this?

Comment: Where's the code that produces the error?  What *is* the error?

Comment: The error is BadImageFormat and I solved it by removing the 256x256 icon from the .ico-file.

Comment: if it solved your problem, you should write that up as your answer.  After a day (or is it 2?) you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the largest size of the icon (256x256) on Windows XP. I simply resaved my icon without the 256x256 image and the problem disappeared.